# Вернуть класс расширяющий иной класс

Tags: java

**Имеется такая ситуация:**

1. *абстрактный* класс **А**
2. класс **В** *расширяющий* **А**
3. класс **С** *расширяющий* **A**

**Хотелось бы:**

Иметь класс **D** в котором есть метод, в зависимости от входного параметра которого, он должен возвращать класс расширяющий класс A(т.е. класс В или С);

**Попытка:**

```
public class D {
    ...
    public <? extends A> getChildA (int number) {
        switch(number){
            case 1:
                return new B();
            case 2:
                return new C();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

но по всей видимости я чего то не понимаю, возможно ли вообще реализовать такое?

**UPD:**

Для полноты картины, приведу пример как хотелось бы использовать данную конструкцию:

```
D.getChildA(1).methodInB1().methodInB2();
D.getChildA(2).methodInC1().methodInC2();
```

**UPD2:**

Для еще более полной картины приведу пример в предполагаемом контексте применения(абстрактно)

```
Server.buildRequest(Server.GET_USERS).setContry(Russia).setDate(16.10.15);
Server.buildRequest(Server.GET_PRODUCTS).setStore(Roga&Kopyta);
```

**UPD3:**

Было выяснено что конструкций такого рода создать нельзя, в таком случае может предложите свой наиболее **эстетичный** вариант построения запроса(фигурирует тип запроса, и набор параметров, индивидуальный для каждого из запросов).

Comment: Вас чем-то не устраивает решения которые привел я? Если да, то хотело бы узнать чем.

Comment: @Vartlok да мне не хотелось бы явно указывать тип B или С...

Comment: Невозможно то что вы хотите. Компилятор должен знать какой класс ему вернулся, опирается при этом он исключительно на сигнатуру метода(куда кстати не входит возвращаемое значение). Как вы себе представляете чтобы компилятор понял, что 1 это класс B, а 2 это класс С? Даже все дженерики которые я использовал это просто красивая обертка. Внутри там всё равно просто кастинг добавляет при компиляции.

Comment: @Vartlok `Невозможно то что вы хотите.` вот в этом и хотелось удостовериться, значит надо закатывать губу)

Comment: А что мешает делать Server.buildRequest(new GetUsers...) и Server.buildRequest(new GetProducts...) ?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov, да как то выглядит не очень, да и пользоваться не удобно, каждый раз надо вспоминать название класса, да еще и названия для них странные...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы хотите чтобы получившийся объект сразу соответствовал нужному классу, то можно сделать так:

```
public <T extends A> T getChildA(Class<T> clazz) {
    if (clazz.equals( B.class )) {
        return (T) new B();
    } else {
        return (T) new C();
    }
}
```

Можно не передавать в метод класс, а передать int. Но тогда компилятор не сможет проверить тип корректно. Т.е. что вы вызовите С с = getChildA(1), что С с = getChildA(2) компилятор это проглотит, только во время выполнения вы можете получите ClassCastException, если укажите не верный параметр. А в случае передачи класса как параметр, будет проверка на этапе компиляции и ошибок будет меньше.

Код для одного int параметра:

```
public <T extends A> T getChildA(int index) {
    if (index == 1) {
        return (T) new B();
    } else {
        return (T) new C();
    }
}

d.<B>getChildA(1);
d.<C>getChildA(2);
```

Comment: да, безусловно так можно, но интересует момент именно с одним интовым параметром

Comment: @droid обновил ответ

Comment: да это полная аналогия (как мне кажется) решения что привел @ЮрийСПб, он не подходит ввиду необходимости после приведения к В или С

Comment: @droid не совсем, чтобы работало прям как вы хотите, я указал пример. В случае же кода от Юрия, вам придётся руками кастить объект.

Answer (score 1):

Да, так можно. Вам надо просто указать `А` как тип возвращаемого значения для вашего метода.

```
public class D {
    ...
    public A getChildA (int number) {
        switch(number){
            case 1:
                return new B();
            case 2:
                return new C();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ну так это понятно, но потом надо приводить к типу B или С...хотелось бы без приведения

Comment: это своего рода метод своего рода билдер, указываю я к примеру 1 и сразу же могу обращаться к методам B класса - типа D.getChildA(1).methodInB1().methodInB2();

Comment: Э-м-м... По моему это низзя реализовать... Возвращаемый тип может быть только один и без приведения не обойтись...А вызывать методы А класса вы сможете и у В и у С, кои будут возвращены методом и без приведения.

Comment: да я в коменте косякнул, методы `B`-класса... D.getChildA(1).methodInB1().methodInB2();

Comment: А почему бы вам не перегрузить тогда метод `getChildA` и возвращать из одного В, а из другого С?

Comment: но для перегрузки надо же менять тип или количество параметров у метода?так ведь

Comment: Ну, насколько я знаю, достаточно поменять тип. Т.е. можно такие методы написать: `B getChildA()` и `C getChildA()`

Comment: нее, already defined

Comment: @droid, lда, вы правы, это я неправильно сказал) Вот тут ест немного полезной инфы: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561436/can-two-java-methods-have-same-name-with-different-return-types

Answer (score 1):

Это называется [фабричным методом.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) В статье есть пример.

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Это была моя первая мысль, но после небольших раздумий я понял, что это не то что хочет вопрошающий. Даже в фабричном методе надо кастить руками, а он по каким-то причинам не хочет(не может) этого сделать.

Comment: фабрика не подходит, так как методы которые хочется Вызвать не находятся в абстрактном `A`